# How to setup Vagrant DNS servers in MacOS without change the DNS in the network setup

Tags: macos, networking, dns, vagrant

I have a vagrant machine and this vm runs a DNS server to resolve the internal domains of each micro-service instance running in a docker container inside the vagrant. Actually, after run `vagrant up`, I need to put the vagrant vm IP address in my network configuration to my computer resolve the development domain, so I can access the application, but the problem is that I work remotelly and frequently I need to connect in public hotspots that uses network authentication and if I have the vagrant DNS in my interface's configuration I could not connect to the hotspot without removing the vagrant IP, but I need to put it back after some minutes later to start working.

So, the question is, there is a way to configure an virtual interface or a VPN interface that points to the vagrant but does not block my network as I describe above ?

When I was using linux, I just put the vagrant IP in the resolv.conf and I had no headaches, but as MacOS does not have the resolv.conf like linux, I could not find a easy way to deal with theses problems.

Comment: I might misunderstood the question but can you create a private network with a static IP for the VM ? so you dont have to change it

Comment: I have a vagrant machine that runs my dev environment and inside this vagrant, has a DNS server that respond to some domains that points to the application environment inside the vagrant.

The problem is, when I start the vagrant, I need to add the vagrant IP to the network setup in the host machine, but in macOS, I need to change the configuration of my network interface manually, I'd like to get a way to configure a new interface (virtual interface like) that setups the vagrant DNS server isolated instead of change my primary interface everytime that I start the env.